# How to change default namespace in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

When beginning to develop my first wp8 app, I noticed that even though when I asked to name the app before starting, The default namespace remained PivotApp1. How do I properly change this to be the name of my actual application?

*Note, right clicking on the project and going to properties to change the default namespace in the application tab does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the code behind file:

1. Right-Click the namespace that you want to change
2. Refactor
3. Rename
4. Type your new name
5. OK

[image]